# Subdomain for Nagios

Tags: apache-httpd, nagios, apache-virtualhost

I have a subdomain forwarding at IP 192.0.2.1 (`example.com`)
Lets call it **nagios**.example.com

Nagios worked at **192.0.2.1/nagios** but now it's not working due to a fact that **app**.example.com took over **default** **apache** **port** (:**80**)

So how to solve my problem? :)

I have **almost** default nagios config in **httpd** vhost except i've added <VirtualHost *:80 > and ServerName.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nagios.example.com

    ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
    #  SSLRequireSSL
       Options ExecCGI
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    #  Order deny,allow
    #  Deny from all
    #  Allow from 127.0.0.1
       AuthName "Nagios Access"
       AuthType Basic
       AuthUserFile /path/file
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>

    Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
    #  SSLRequireSSL
       Options None
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    #  Order deny,allow
    #  Deny from all
    #  Allow from 127.0.0.1
       AuthName "Nagios Access"
       AuthType Basic
       AuthUserFile /path/file
       Require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PS: 
    httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS

```
    VirtualHost configuration:    

wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain-alias.example (/etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain-alias.example (/etc/httpd/conf.d/app.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost nagios.example.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf:8)
Syntax OK
```

Sorry for "domain-alias.example" but it's kind of private information :)

Comment: What is output of `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my question with answer for your question :)

Comment: @Gnouc : any other ideas? I'm still stuck with this!! :D

Comment: @Mr.TK - do you want both the `/nagios` URL to work and the `nagios.dom.com`?

Comment: @sim - Thank You for your comment. No, i just want the nagios.domain.com to work.

Comment: @slm: Great - i misspelled your nickname :D

Comment: @Mr.TK - np. In Nagios you can change the html_url_path to `/` instead of `/nagios`. That'll get it responding to just the `http://hostname/`. You'll want to change your `Alias` to `/` in the `httpd.conf` abovev from `/nagios` too. http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html

Comment: @Mr.TK - with the typo I did not see your reply until just now. Otherwise I would've replied sooner.

Comment: @slm: :)
Well, that's not the problem now:
I've got xx.xx.xx.xx:8083 working and the problem is that i can't access hostname/nagios because it's app.hostname which takes over nagios - app.hostname it's an web app and it's showing 404 - page not found ;)

Comment: @slm: also :) It's not working xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/nagios when i remove /nagios from virtualhost and html_url_path :/ I really need port forwarding from xx.xx...:8083 to localhost/nagios

Comment: @Mr.TK - if you need port forwarding you can setup a reverse proxy w/in Apache to handle things like this. The apache mod is called `mod_proxy`. I might be inclined to solve you issue that way instead of mucking around with moving Nagios all around. There's an example of how to do this here: http://akerneladay.com/httpd-reverse-proxy-nagiosxi-step-back-in-time/

Comment: @slm I am really grateful! I'm gonna check this out ASAP. :)

Comment: @Mr.TK - np, let me know how you make out. I've been using Nagios + Apache/Nginx for 10+ yrs and have a fairly long history with using it 8-)

Comment: @slm :) Your the best!! 
I am so close!! :) And all thanks to Your hints!
 nagios.domain.com takes me to the nagios (I know that because there is an Auth and i successfully logged in.
      BUT! :D This little fella 


`Alias / "/usr/local/nagios/share"`

Generates new trouble :D 
_You don't have permission to access / on this server._

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vhost internaly it is always better solution to make vhost configuration with different ports, so in this case you can setup nagios domain on 8083 port:
first step:
In httpd.conf you need to spicify listening ports:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 80
Listen 8083
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf add a NameVirtualHost for every virtual host you want to add.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:8083
```

Adopt your documetn root to requested ports and that's it.

After restarting the srevice you can check if ports are open and which app use the same with:

```
netstat -tlnp
```

Comment: `Listen 8083
NameVirtualHost *:8083`

And at vhost:

`<VirtualHost *:8083>`
and still nothing :/ Port is opened in iptables.

Comment: Also: i've tried adding `127.0.0.1:8083 nagios.domain.com` at /etc/hosts

Comment: which error you have when you issue localhost:8083 in browser ?

Comment: It does work - it's not localhost but still: `ip:port = it's working 
xxxx:8083/nagios`

Comment: Sum up: nagios.domain.com is not working (app.domain.com is triggering) , but ip:port/nagios does trigger the nagios)

Comment: sorry, when i meant localhost i meant actually on ip address:8083/nagios, so it is ok

Comment: Yes, of course, but :) I would like to make it nagios.domain.com, not address:8083/nagios
I am grateful for all You have done for me (+1 for You) . :)
But still my question is not answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your port to VirtualHost *:8080 or 81.

see if that works. I had a similar issue with a conflict on my apache server at work and i changed the virtualHost to port 8080 and now everything is runnning fine.

Comment: Solution similar to klerk's solution and same result :D
It's not working... :)

Comment: have you looked at your ISP to see if it blocking the original port that you had it on. Sometimes that can happen. Also on you firewall configuration are you allowing ssh and httpd.

Comment: Yes yes yes :) Other subdomains are done the very same way as I want the nagios.domain.com to work.
Firewall is not an issue for sure. :) 
Nagios is accesbile from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/nagios thx to klerk's answer.

Comment: I found a post that should help you figure out why it isn't working for you. [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/network-installaion-with-subdomains-on-xampp) They talk about subdomains and why it stopped working and have links to other sights that explain more in detail on how to fix that specific issue.

Comment: are you running mulitple domain through the same address

Comment: THX... gonna check this out tomorrow or sunner.

Comment: also make sure that you have port forwarding done. if you have your other ports forwarding to you *:80 port then you should be good on the part also